# accessing route from a laravel project in docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js

Good afternoon,

I'm using the Argon Dashboard 2 template

Backend: laravel/Docker
Frontend: vueJS

When I access the Login route, it works fine. However, when the route is called: `$response = $http->get('http://apis_laravel:8000/api/v2/me/1');`
generates an error if it did not find the route.

This route: `$response = $http->get('http://apis_laravel:8000/api/v2/me/1');`
is called from within the login function on the front.

When I test it in postman it works fine. I believe it is something related to the back-end docker container. Can someone help me?

```
{
    "message": "Undefined array key \"authorization\"",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V2/MeController.php",
    "line": 28,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php",
            "line": 254,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {

{
    "message": "Undefined array key \"authorization\"",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V2/MeController.php",
    "line": 28,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php",
            "line": 254,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
```

Comment: It's impossible to say anything here without the relevant contents from `app/Http/Controllers/Api/V2/MeController.php`.